# Typescript infer return type as superset of parameter using Pick

Tags: typescript

I want to define a reusable function that will take the minimal arguments needed to perform it's logic, but return the entire object it was passed, without needing to use a generic. For example

```
const getMyTodos = (idUser: string, todos: Pick<Todo, 'id' | 'idUser'>) => {
  return todos.filter((todo) => todo.idUser === idUser);
};
```

Where i can use getMyTodos with any todos array, so long as it has at least id and idUser.

```
getMyTodos('xyz', [{ id: '1', idUser: 'xyz', someOtherProperty: 'blah' }]);
// inferred return type is { id: string; idUser: string; someOtherProperty: string; 
// rather than just id and idUser.
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8CwAUMicsJgFzIDOYUoA5gNxGlmYCq10Vt9IzVqWroAthADyYABbQAClHQAHaGACevOoxaEAvkSIJ0IWsgYQwAWTUZs1ZAF5kACnJceNLQIA0yMFnRqKjlgBABrAB5bdF8AcnJY5AAfZHjObihYgD4AbQBdAEpHLLwhEigLAFcoED8A6gA6GGAAG0goZ2d-bCKHEu70BrcMxwcnYegCnV0dQ2NTAA9HMwtraOpnWIW1AC9Y3xzcdiot3f32dygTyoyARkTdQp0FnIAGPIaRcSlZKAVlVRqZAAemByGwEHsIHQYGQAHd0FAwkA)

Is this possible? I thought Pick would let typescript infer this automatically, but that appears to not be the case.

Comment: Where does the "without needing to use a generic" constraint come from? Your `Pick<>` is also generic.

Comment: "without needing to use a generic" makes this either impossible or ill-advised.  It's like saying "I want to drive a nail into a wall, without needing to use a hammer".  Maybe there's some way to do that, but it would be much better to just use a hammer.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) parameter, specifying a base type for `todos`.

```js
function getMyTodos
  <Filterable extends Pick<Todo, 'id' | 'idUser'>>
   (idUser: string, todos: Filterable[])
    : Filterable[]
{
  return todos.filter((todo) => todo.idUser === idUser);
}
```

typescript will infer `Filterable`, accepting any type that has at least your `Pick`ed properties, and return the filtered array using that same type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8CwAUMicsJgFzIDOYUoA5gNxGlmYCq10Vt9IzVqWroAthADyYABbQAClHQAHaGACevOoxaEAvkSIJ0IWsgYQwAWTUZs1ZAF5kAHgBiwADaQocAEYeUCAAPSBBMezlgBABrZ1t0ABpkAHJyZOQAHxTyLmhkgD58gAoc7ihNfgYksCx0aip3L2g-AIBtAF0ASgbPbxaIDsd8vCESKAsAVygQZBq7ADoYXugiorn0TqHZ2vnS6EcHJz2oTp1dHUNjUyDHMwtreOoi5KC1AC9kpNbcdioX98+7Fy5RSEzKAEZASJxFJZFAFMpVBpkAAiODUTAwFHIXRdC6EIKtAAM7Xm0MkMnkihUUHUyAA9PTkNgIPYAO7oKDRIA)